# Set timeout for HTTP POST request returning JSON

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I am running HTTP requests against an API which occasionally is super slow, meaning I need to extend its timeout value. The API returns a simple JSON array of `Dimension` objects. This my `POST` request that works just fine:

```
autodetect(configuration: IntegConfig): Observable<Dimension[]> {
      return this.http.post<any>(this.setupAPIUrl + `autodetect`, configuration);
}
```

So all I needed was to add a timeout to that request. Turns out, this is not as easy as I anticipated. This is what I tried:

```
autodetect(configuration: IntegConfig): Observable<Dimension[]> {
      const options = {
          timeout: 300000
        };
      return this.http.post<any>(this.setupAPIUrl + `autodetect`, configuration, options);
}
```

This yields in a compile time error:

```
Type 'ArrayBuffer' is missing the following properties from type 'Dimension[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more.
```

I realized that the `http.post` method has quite a few overloads returning different kinds of objects. However, I did not see how to simply set a timeout on any of those and keeping the same return type.

I found some similar questions here, some suggesting to set the `options` parameter as `any` type, but that did not change anything. Others suggested to set an expected return type in `post<T>` like this:

```
return this.http.post<Dimension[]>(this.setupAPIUrl + `autodetect`, configuration, options);
```

But that did not help at all. I also attempted to set the parameters such that I would hit a particular overload:

```
const options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders(),
  observe: 'events' as const,
  params: new HttpParams(),
  reportProgress: false,
  responseType: 'json' as const,
  withCredentials: false,
  timeout: 200000
};
```

How do I set a simple HTTP timeout on a POST request?

Comment: `.post` _does_ have a lot of overloads, for various combinations of inputs and return types, but it's not clear where you got the idea that _any_ of them supported a `timeout` property: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aangular%2Fangular+timeout+path%3Apackages%2Fcommon%2Fhttp%2Fsrc&type=code. Also note there's a limit to Angular's control of this - you can add a _shorter_ timeout to any observable with RxJS, but eventually the browser itself will give up on the request.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Thanks for the clarification. Developing mostly in C# i simply assumed I would have control over the timeout value on client side as well, I didn't know that wasn't possible. Sadly, I don't have control over the slow API endpoint either.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your TypeScript error, avoid using the `any` type.

You could rewrite your method like this:

```js
autodetect(configuration: IntegConfig): Observable<Dimension[]> {
  return this.http.post<Dimension[]>(this.setupAPIUrl + 'autodetect', configuration);
}
```

If you prefer using template literals, use:

```js
`${this.setupAPIUrl}autodetect`
```

As [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) mentioned in his comment, you could use a `timeout` RxJS operator but only to apply a shorter timeout than the browser's default setting.

Here is how you could write it:

```js
autodetect(configuration: IntegConfig): Observable<Dimension[]> {
  return this.http.post<Dimension[]>(this.setupAPIUrl + 'autodetect', configuration)
    .pipe(timeout(1000));
}
```